# I am having trouble getting an ajax request data to show up in each dynamically created form in Django

Tags: django, ajax, formset

My Django project has an app that registers sales which needs to have multiple forms saved all  at once using Django formsets, I have managed to get the dynamic forms working but it needs improvement so that with a product selected in each form, the product price may appear on the price field dynamically and the total price (product_price * quantity) may also appear in the its respective field.

My code only shows the first form's price but when I add new forms (dynamically) they all appear with the the price of the first form and not the price of the product selected in in each form.

My sale models...

```
class Product(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(editable=False, unique=True, verbose_name=_("product id"))
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name=_("is active"))
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name=_("product name"))
    cost_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2, verbose_name=_("cost price"))
    retail_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2, verbose_name=_("retail price"))

class ProductSale(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(editable=False, unique=True, verbose_name=_("product sale id"))
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name=_("product"))
    retail_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name=_("retail price"))
    quantity = models.SmallIntegerField(verbose_name=_("quantity"))
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name=_("total"))
```

The form...

```
ProductSaleFormset = modelformset_factory(
ProductSale,
fields=("product", "quantity"),
extra=1,
localized_fields="__all__",
widgets={
    "product": forms.Select(
        attrs={
            "id": "id_product",
            "class": "form-control",
            "style": "width:350px",
        }
    ),
    "quantity": forms.NumberInput(
        attrs={
            "id": "id_quantity",
            "class": "form-control",
            "style": "width:180px",
        },
    ),
},

)
```

The html...

```
<form method="POST" action="">{% csrf_token %}
             <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>{{ pos_sale_form.client.label }}</label>
                        {{ pos_sale_form.client }}
                    </div>

                </div>
                 <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>{{ pos_sale_form.payment_method.label }}</label>
                        {{ pos_sale_form.payment_method }}
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-hover table-white">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th style="width: 20px">#</th>
                                <th class="col-sm-2">{% trans "Item" %}</th>
                                <th style="width:100px;">{% trans "Retail Price" %}</th>
                                <th style="width:80px;">{% trans "Qty" %}</th>
                                <th>{% trans "Amount" %}</th>
                                <th></th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>


                            {{ formset.management_form }}

                            {% for form in formset.forms %}

                            <tr class="col form-col spacer">
                                <td>{{ form.id }}</td>
                                <td>
                                    {{ form.product }}
                                    {{ form.product.help_text }}
                                    <p  class="text text-danger">{{ form.product.errors|striptags }}</p>
                                    <!--                                        <input class="form-control" type="text" style="min-width:150px">-->
                                </td>
                                <td data-unit-cost="{{ form.product.retail_price }}">
                                    <input class="form-control" id="id_product_price" style="width:100px" type="text">
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    {{ form.quantity }}
                                    {{ form.quantity.help_text }}
                                    <p  class="text text-danger">{{ form.quantity.errors|striptags }}</p>

                                    <!--                                        <input class="form-control" style="width:80px" type="text">-->
                                </td>
                                <td data-total-price="{{ form.total }}">
                                    <input class="form-control" id="id_total_price" style="width:180px" type="text" placeholder="0">
                                </td>

                                <td class="input-group-append">
                                    <button class="btn btn-success add-form-col">+</button>
                                </td>

                            </tr>
                            {% endfor %}

                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-hover table-white">
                            <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="5" class="text-right">
                                    {% trans "Discount" %} %
                                </td>
                                <td style="text-align: right; padding-right: 30px;width: 230px">
                                    {{ pos_sale_form.discount }}
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="5" style="text-align: right; font-weight: bold">
                                    {% trans "Grand Total" %}
                                </td>
                                <td id="grand_total" style="text-align: right; padding-right: 30px; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px;width: 230px">
                                    0.00
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="text-center m-t-20">
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg " type="submit">{% trans "Sell" %}</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

The script...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function getProductPrice() {
   $('#id_product').change(function(){
  var product = $(this).val();
  console.log(product);
  $.ajax({
      url : "{% url 'stock:product-retail-price' %}",
      type : "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      data : {
          "product" : product,
          },
      success: function(json) {
          document.getElementById('id_product_price').value=json.retail_price;
          document.getElementById('id_total_price').value=json.total_price;
      },
      failure: function(json) {
          alert('Got an error dude');
      }
  });
});
};


function updateElementIndex(el, prefix, ndx) {
    var id_regex = new RegExp('(' + prefix + '-\\d+)');
    var replacement = prefix + '-' + ndx;
    if ($(el).attr("for")) $(el).attr("for", $(el).attr("for").replace(id_regex, replacement));
    if (el.id) el.id = el.id.replace(id_regex, replacement);
    if (el.name) el.name = el.name.replace(id_regex, replacement);


}
function cloneMore(selector, prefix) {
    var newElement = $(selector).clone(true);
    var total = $('#id_' + prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val();
    newElement.find(':input:not([type=button]):not([type=submit]):not([type=reset])').each(function() {
        var name = $(this).attr('name')

        if(name) {

            name = name.replace('-' + (total-1) + '-', '-' + total + '-');
            var id = 'id_' + name;
            $(this).attr({'name': name, 'id': id}).val('').removeAttr('checked');

        }
    });
    newElement.find('label').each(function() {
        var forValue = $(this).attr('for');
        if (forValue) {

          forValue = forValue.replace('-' + (total-1) + '-', '-' + total + '-');
          $(this).attr({'for': forValue});

        }
    });
    total++;
    $('#id_' + prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val(total);
    $(selector).after(newElement);
    var conditionRow = $('.form-col:not(:last)');
    conditionRow.find('.btn.add-form-col')
    .removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-danger')
    .removeClass('add-form-col').addClass('remove-form-col')
    .html('-');

    return false;
}
function deleteForm(prefix, btn) {
    var total = parseInt($('#id_' + prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val());
    if (total > 1){
        btn.closest('.form-col').remove();
        var forms = $('.form-col');
        $('#id_' + prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val(forms.length);
        for (var i=0, formCount=forms.length; i<formCount; i++) {
            $(forms.get(i)).find(':input').each(function() {
                updateElementIndex(this, prefix, i);
            });
        }
    }
    return false;
}
$(document).on('click', '.add-form-col', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    cloneMore('.form-col:last', 'form');
    return false;
});
$(document).on('click', '.remove-form-col', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    deleteForm('form', $(this));
    return false;
});


$(document).ready(
   getProductPrice()
);

</script>
```

The ajax view...

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.views.decorators.http import require_GET
from .models import Product

@login_required
@require_GET
def get_product_retail_price(request):
    product_id = request.GET["product"]
    product_quantity = request.GET.get("id_quantity")
    if product_id:
        try:
            retail_price = Product.objects.get(id=product_id).retail_price
            total_price = retail_price * product_quantity if product_quantity else 0
            response_data = {"retail_price": retail_price, "total_price": total_price}
            return JsonResponse(response_data)
        except Product.DoesNotExist:
            pass
    return JsonResponse({"status": "error"})
```

Comment: I've repaired the code in the two first classes - please check the edit is OK.